# Delete specific character on previous line

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I deleted lines in a file with

```
:g/^\s*key3/d
```

and now have a file like this:

```
entry{entryname1,
    key1 = {text},
    key2 = {text},
}

entry{entryname2,
    anotherkey = {text},
    yetanotherkey = {text}
}
...
```

I want to delete the trailing comma after key2 (the name of the last key can change) on multiple lines in the file.

Is there a command (or multiple commands) that does the following:

```
for each line with the pattern ^}$:
  if the last character in the previous line is a comma:
    delete that comma
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:g` again with a regular expression, but use a line offset of -1 to have the global command act on the lines above the match.

Then you can use that to apply a `:s` command to remove any trailing commas.

Putting it all together:

```
:g/^{$/-1s/,$//
```

These offsets are explained in [section 10.3](https://vimhelp.org/usr_10.txt.html#10.3) of the Vim manual:

> **ADD AND SUBTRACT**
>
> There is a slight error in the above command: If the title of the next chapter
>   had included "grey" it would be replaced as well.  Maybe that's what you wanted, but what if you didn't?  Then you can specify an offset.
>
> To search for a pattern and then use the line above it:
>
> ```
> /Chapter/-1
> ```

etc.

Documentation under [`:help cmdline-ranges`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges) has more advanced examples. Even though the discussion is mainly around ranges preceding a command, many of those expressions will work after `:g` as well.

Comment: Same answer, just took me longer to type! :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Looks great to me! I actually took some time looking for references. This is an area where I think the docs are not very direct as they usually are, since `:g` takes a pattern but that usually behaves more like ranges do, with line offsets and `;` to introduce a second pattern (I believe those work too.)

Comment: yeah `:g` is one of the more powerful commands, but deciphering it can be hard! The trick I always use is that global defines a set of lines to operator over, a bit like `for line matching /pat/, execute cmd with the current line as $line` (kind of like Awk)—then, adding a range to `cmd` makes perfect sense; it starts from `$line` if it's relative or pattern-based.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a number of ways to make this work:

First would be only the `key2` case:

```
global/key2/substitute/,$//
```

Now, in the general case, I believe you want to do

```
global/^}$/-substitute/,$//
```

`:global` can be abbreviated to `:g` and `:substitute` to `:s`. `-` in the range here is equivalent to `-1`, as explained at `:help [range]`.

There's one other way to note: `:g/^}$/-normal! 0f,x` should work if there's only one comma in the lines you want to modify, and none in the lines you want to leave alone—this works because `normal!` will stop if any of the given commands fail. Since `f,` will fail when there's no comma, `x` will never be executed.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret your question thus: wherever in the file you have comma followed by new-line that contains only }, delete all such commas.

```
:%s/,\n}$/\r}/
```

\n in the pattern identifies a line break, \r in replacement inserts a line break. I've no idea why they should be different.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I often have to do an edit over because I'm too hasty to check it the 1st time.